# Spring MVC - accessing a file in res folder under web

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, path, resources

my project structure is like this:

[image]

I need to be able to access a json file within my service layer. I am having trouble with the path to get it. This is the code I am using to see if the file exists, but I get null pointer exception each time.

```
public String parseGeoJson(String filePath) {
        System.out.println("start");

        File file = new File(getClass().getResource("/res/files/maryland2010Final.json").getFile());
        if (file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("here");
            return "good";
        }
        System.out.println("end");
        return "bad";
    }
```

An error is thrown at the getResource line. My dispatcher maps the resources

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/res/css/**" location="res/css/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/res/img/**" location="res/img/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/res/js/**" location="res/js/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/res/files/**" location="res/files/" />
```

I really have no idea, I have tried different ways I found online, like classpath: , etc. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `getResource("/web/res/files/maryland2010Final.json")` ?

Comment: yes I have, it gives same error. I am now trying
        Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("/web/res/files/maryland2010Final.json"); and testing if that exists. It does not but it does not throw an error

Comment: Please export the project as a war file and take a look if the web directory (or its contents) are inside.

Comment: I see the problem. It has something to do with intellij not registering my files folder. I am also having this same issue in my front-end where I can not get anything from that files directory. In my war_exploded res folder, everything is there as it should be